# Junit for Bean Definition class

Tags: java, spring, junit

As am a beginner in writing junit test case, I have no idea to write junit to bean loader class, Can anybody suggest me how to write junit for my bean loader, Below is my piece of code:

My Bean loader is of cassandra properties:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("cassandra.properties")
@EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackages = "...repository")
public class Beanloader {

    @Autowired
    public Environment environment;

    CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster = new CassandraClusterFactoryBean();

    @Bean(name = "clusterFactory")
    public CassandraClusterFactoryBean getCluster() {
        PoolingOptions poolingOptions = new PoolingOptions();
        cluster.setContactPoints(environment.getProperty("cassandra.contactpoints"));
        cluster.setPoolingOptions(poolingOptions);
        cluster.setPort(Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty("cassandra.port")));
        poolingOptions.setNewConnectionThreshold(HostDistance.LOCAL, 50);

        return cluster;
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("clusterFactory")
    public CassandraSessionFactoryBean getSession() throws Exception {
        CassandraSessionFactoryBean session = new CassandraSessionFactoryBean();
        session.setCluster(cluster.getObject());
        session.setKeyspaceName(environment.getProperty("cassandra.keyspace"));
        session.setConverter(new MappingCassandraConverter(new CassandraMappingContextAware()));
        session.setSchemaAction(SchemaAction.NONE);

        return session;
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraOperations cassandraTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new CassandraTemplate(getSession().getObject());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also beginner, but I think that what you search (test a config class) is an integration tests not unit test ?

Comment: ya, it is a integration test level, but i need it to be done in unit testing, can anyone help me in this

Comment: Can Anyone help me in this issue